# Does ML.Net's AutoML normalize data?

Tags: c#, ml.net, automl

I'm using the AutoML API for ML.Net, and I see from the docs that it does a bunch of data [pre-processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/how-to-use-the-automl-api) for me. What I don't see though is if it normalizes each of the feature columns for me or not. My question is: Does AutoML normalize my data for me? If so, do I have any control as to how it normalizes? If not, how would I do this given that I'm not creating a pipeline that I see all the other normalization [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/prepare-data-ml-net) use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience AutoML engine automatically adds affine normalizer to Ols regression models, all other types don't get any normalization. You can add normalizer as the preFeaturizer argument to the [Execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.automl.experimentbase-2.execute?view=ml-dotnet-preview#microsoft-ml-automl-experimentbase-2-execute(microsoft-ml-idataview-microsoft-ml-automl-columninformation-microsoft-ml-iestimator((microsoft-ml-itransformer))-system-iprogress((microsoft-ml-automl-rundetail((-0)))))) method, e.g.

preFeaturizer: mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeLpNorm(featuresColumnName, featuresColumnName)

Comment: So if I understand this right, I can use all the pipeline stuff in advance and slap that onto the execute method - right?

Comment: I've only worked with normalizers, but I'm quite sure that is right.